# Does IE8 recognize state attribute changes via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, attributes, state

I am using jQuery to change a state attribute from 0 to 1. It seems to be working fine in all modern browsers, but is not working in IE8. I have been unable to determine if I am merely doing something wrong or if IE8 does not recognize state attribute changes.

Here is the code:

```
$('#selection-information').attr('state', 1);
     acc.children('.step').each(function(i){
        if($(this).attr('state') == 0) 
        {
    next = i;
    return false;
    }
})
    if(whichButton=='complete'){
     acc.accordion('activate',next);
```

For what it's worth, I asked a question related to the above in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089767/why-wont-jquery-accordion-section-activate-in-ie-8).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ie8 recognize all attributes as string

So you can try:

```
($(this).attr('state') == "0")
```

or

```
parseInt($(this).attr('state')) == 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not seem to make a difference.